# phpspec and laravel setup

Tags: laravel, phpspec

I am setting up a new Laravel project and integrating PHPSpec. I am having trouble finding a good working example of the phpspec.yml file that would work neatly with Laravel. In a similar way to RSpec in Rails.

My desired folder structure would be as follows

```
spec/
    models/
    controllers/
app/
    models/
    controllers/
```

My phpspec.yml currently looks like this:

```
suites:
controller_suite:
    namespace: Controller
    spec_path: 'spec/controllers'
    src_path: 'app/controllers'

model_suite:
    namespace: Model
    spec_path: 'spec/models'
    src_path: 'app/models'
```

I copied my Model related tests in the spec/models folder, but when I 'phpspec run' it does not run any of them. 
I also realise that the namespace is not 'Model' and 'Controller' in Laravel, perhaps more like Eloquent and BaseController..

I am also using this extension: https://github.com/BenConstable/phpspec-laravel

I'm not sure how to set this up and cannot find any working examples. 
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
Advice founbd on another forum from Jeffrey Way:

> You can test your controllers with Behat. PHPSpec isn't a substitute
>   for it (or Codeception).

UPDATE:

I've since decided to use Codeception instead as it seems to integrate neatly into Laravel and widely used.

Comment: I know you've since decided to go with Codeception, but there is a free video on Laracasts (By Jeffrey Way I believe) which describes how to use phpspec with Laravel.  It's about 15 minutes long, but I thought it was time well spent.   https://laracasts.com/lessons/phpspec-laravel-and-refactoring

Comment: @user3158900 thanks I will check that out, looks like its more designed for unit testing, and that a combination of phpspec and codeception could work..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Kindly answered via email from [Ben Constable](https://github.com/BenConstable) :

> Setting up PHPSpec with Laravel with its default file layout is pretty difficult, and I haven’t yet figured out how to do it. However, you can get it working with a slightly different layout, like:
>
> ```
> - app
>     - Controllers
>         - MyController.php
>     - Models
>         - MyModel.php
> - spec
>     - Controllers
>         - MyControllerSpec.php
>     - Models
>         - MyModelSpec.php
> ```
>
> then, in your `phpspec.yml` you’d have:
>
> ```
> extensions:
>     - PhpSpec\Laravel\Extension\LaravelExtension
>
> suites:
>     laravel_controller_suite:
>         namespace: Controllers
>         src_path: app
>     laravel_model_suite:
>         namespace: Models
>         src_path: app
>
> laravel_extension:
>     testing_environment: 'testing'
> ```
>
> and finally, you’d need to modify your `composer.json` to include `app/` in the autoload class map. Your models, controllers and whatever would then be namespaced, like:
>
> ```
> <?php namespace Controllers;
>
> use Controller;
>
> class MyController extends Controller {}
> ```
>
> That should sort you out. Just as an aside, when I’ve been making Laravel projects I’ve been putting everything in `app/src/MyVendor/MyNamespace/Controllers` etc, which I prefer as a layout (keeps the source away from the config and other files, and is similar to the layout of Laravel Packages).
>
> In the future, I will try and look into it and see if I can get PHPSpec working with the default Laravel layout - I’ll update the project on GitHub if/when I do.

Comment: Thanks to Ben for this. I was completely lost as to why mine wasn't working and then saw this extensions item. I wasn't even trying to test controllers and models, just my own classes but an error was being thrown in the cli **after** my tests had passed.

Answer (score 2):

For those using Laravel 5.x and PhpSpec 4.x, you can tweak with the [PSR4 prefix configuration](http://www.phpspec.net/en/stable/cookbook/configuration.html#spec-and-source-locations) in order to make PhpSpec compatible with the Laravel layout.

My project used this configuration:

```
suites:
    app:
        namespace: App
        src_path: app
        psr4_prefix: App
        spec_prefix: classes
        spec_path: specs
```

Comment: I struggled with this for quite some time. Combining spec_prefix and spec_path did the trick, thanks for sharing.