# How to testing Laravel 6 using PHPSpec?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6, phpspec

I already search it on Google for a while, and I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323536/phpspec-and-laravel-setup) article but the package that using for this article is not support Laravel 6, I want to use PHPSpec but I don't want to use older Laravel versions,

so I already tried using my PHPSpec yml config, but I'm not sure how to make it better for Laravel file structures.

Is there anyone that using Laravel 6 and know how to integrates with PHPSpec the correct way? so it'll be as close as possible with this [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22323536/phpspec-and-laravel-setup) I found. Thanks!

**EDIT**

I just change the config, and here is the config now

**phpspec.yml**

```
suites:
  laravel_controller_suite:
    namespace: Servers
    src_path: app/Controllers
    spec_path: spec/Controllers
    spec_prefix: spec

  laravel_model_suite:
    namespace: Servers
    src_path: app/Models
    spec_path: spec/Models
    spec_prefix: spec
```

but when I execute `phpspec describe Servers/Controllers/PageController`

it's creates the directory to something like this,

[image]

how to fix it?

**EDIT**

My Laravel namespace is `Servers`

Comment: Possible [here](https://laracasts.com/lessons/phpspec-laravel-and-refactoring) your solution?

Comment: @SimoneRossaini Hi, thanks for the comment, but I already tried that, and I'm not sure how to make it the best way for Laravel 6, as the file structures is changed and I want to make it scalable as well.